# How to send app request in iphone/php webservices to facebook in using query string

Tags: php, iphone

I want to send request by simple query string but I have problems with getting notification on facebook. Also when I send the request and I pass the id of receiver in (to) parameter then I get the request on my own id.

How could I send the app request and get the notification on facebook ?.

I use php webservices for iphone so please do not write pop type. Please, use query string concept so i will pass it in curl.

Comment: Your question is too broad - try adding some example code or include more specific detail

Comment: I think this question is pretty simple, when we run some php webservice in browser, facebook allows pop-up option while the same webservice call in iPhone won't allow pop-up for fb requests, so how can one send the same here w/o use of pop-up via request URL or something tricky..

Comment: Sorry We can not pop up in i phone so any other method to popup and support iphone mobile browser that's good idea.